# Correct way to add entry to a database only if entry does not exist; using python + peewee

Tags: python, mysql, database, peewee

I've been encountering the following pattern recently:

I have a table in mysql with a (possibly composite) primary key defined. There are some entries in the table already.

I am running some update scripts which push new entries to the table. The scripts are designed to be ran repeatedly and they might try to push duplicate entries.

Very often I end up in a situation where I have a dataframe and I would like to only push the new rows in the mysql table.

e.g.
peewee model:

```
class MyTable(pwe.Model):
  colA = pwe.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  colB = pwe.IntegerField()
```

example dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]], columns=['colA','colB'])
>>> df
   colA  colB
0     1     2
1     2     3
2     3     4
```

### Attempted solutions

I've tried a number of solutions, but none is ideal:

1. Use `MyTable.get_or_create`. Not recommended for large amounts of data.
2. Use `MyTable.insert_many()` or `MyTable.batch_create()` and manually check which entries are already in the db:

```
    with MyTable._meta.database.atomic():
        existing_keys = [r.colA for r in MyTable.select(MyTable.colA)]
        df = df[~df['colA'].isin(existing_keys)]
        MyTable.batch_create([MyTable(**rec) for rec in df.to_dict('records')])
```

I have multiple issues with this.

- it's just ugly.
- it's kinda long.
- I don't want to pull down the entire `colA` whenever I want to make an update.
- I'm not sure this handles concurrency issues - what if someone else pushes data in between my computing `existing_keys` and calling `batch_create`?

### Question

What is the recommended way of pushing large amounts of data to a table, when some of the rows might already exist in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database, but most support some kind of INSERT OR IGNORE / INSERT ... ON CONFLICT IGNORE. So you can do a batch insert and rely on the primary key or some other unique constraint to trigger the "OR IGNORE" logic.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Insert.on_conflict